# Строка статуса для DBGrid

Tags: c++builder, dbgrid, delphi

Привет всем.

Есть такая надобность - в VCL (работаю в 6-ом Билдере) к гриду на форме добавить вроде строки статуса где - под соотвествуюшую колонку - добавить какое-то агрегатное значение (количество, сумма, и т.д.)
Заодно может подскажите их правильное название?
Я знаю что такое есть "из коробки" для некоторых платных наборов компонент (девэкспресс и тому подобное), но я хотел бы знать как делать своими руками - либо со стандартными компонентами, либо JVCL-евскими.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне посоветовали - если пользую JVCL - для этих нужд использовать `TJvDBGridFooter` в купе с `TJvDBGrid`.